# MongoDB: Design Model for like to a post, should I use "array" or "multiple documents"? Which one is the best for query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

[image]

[image]

Hello, I am designing a database for my collage project using mongoDB.
The project is like a social app, and there will be a **like button** for each post. 
The question is:

> How should I store the users for each like they click on a post?

What I concern is that using array could make the query faster, but I have to control the size of the array. 
And using multiple document I have no idea if it would make it query as fast as or not too slower than using array when using postid as index.


Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I read your question in both approaches. I need to prefer the second approach. if you need to handle a large-scale database then you must use the second approach. because it makes a good effect on your database performance. in the second approach, you can easily modify your data. In future, you can add index easily for better performance

Comment: Thanks I also choose the second method.